# Выпадающий список в таблице

Tags: css3, table

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой список?
Чтобы при наличии нескольких колонок он растягивался на всю ширину и при этом смещал содержимое вниз (а не перекрывал его)

Заранее спасибо за наводки и идеи!